Velocity vector vs Matrix Differential
I am having trouble understanding the equivalence of taking the derivative of the matrix and taking the velocity vector. I came across a proof of the Lie Algebra of $O(n)$ as follows:
Let $\gamma(t)$ be an smooth curve in $O(n)$ such that $\gamma(0)=I_n,\gamma'(0)=A$.
Then, $\gamma(t)^T\gamma(t)=I_n$, take the derivative at $0$, we have $$
0=\gamma'(0)^T\gamma(0)+\gamma(0)^T\gamma'(0)=A^T+A
$$
Let $A$ be any $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix. Notice that $$\text{Exp}(A)^T\text{Exp}(A)=\text{Exp}(A^T)\text{Exp}(A)=\text{Exp}(-A)\text{Exp}(A)=I_n$$
Thus, $\text{Exp}(A)\in O(n)$ and $\text{Exp}(tA)\in O(n)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\text{Exp}(tA)=A$, $A$ is the velocity vector of the curve $\text{Exp}(tA)$ at $I_n$. Thus, $A\in\mathfrak{o}(n)$.
The interchanging of the role of $A$ as both a tangent vector and matrix confuses me a lot but here is what I understood. Every tangent vector at identity is the velocity vector of some smooth curve passing through $I_n$, which after reparameterization can be centered at $0$, becoming the velocity vector of a smooth curve at $0$, denoted $\gamma'(0).$ So, technically the first part is saying, let $\overline{A}\in T_{I_n}O(n)$, there exists a smooth curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=I_n$ and $\gamma'(t)=\overline{A}$. But then, I am confused on how the matrix derivative is indeed the cooresponding matrix of the tangent vector, specifically why is $\gamma'(0)=A=[d\iota_{I_n}(\overline{A})]_\epsilon$ (here $\gamma'(0)$ is thought as taking the ordinary derivative)? where $\epsilon$ is the coordinate basis for $T_{I_n}GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ under the standard global coordinate chart $(GL_n(\mathbb{R}),(x^{ij}))$

If you have problems imaginaing the group manifold of a Lie group, use the canonical map $$ \mathbb C^{n\times n} \leftrightarrow \mathbb C^{n^2},$$  commuting with all analytic operations in a given representation, shifted by a group translation to a neighborhood  of $\mathbb 1$..

Isn't a tangent vector by definition the derivative of a path at a point? At least for a submanifold of a Euclidean space.

This correspondence is due to the properties of the exponential map $\gamma(t) = e^{tA}$; it wouldn't work with another curve.
